# Reload of page shall empty the form fields

Tags: javascript, flask

I am trying to implement the following logic: when the user reloads the page with data already loaded from file, the form fields shall be emptied. Since, there is no reload event, I tried to show similar behavior of this event with the following js code:

```
var visited = 0;

    function init() {
        if(document.getElementById("textarea1").innerText!=="Reload") {//this line indicates from the content of textarea if the page is reloaded
            if (visited === 1) {
                alert("Inside");
                document.getElementById("ForTesting").click();// when this button pressed the form data is emptied
                document.submitForm.submit();
                visited=0;
            }

            visited=1;
            alert(visited);
        }
    }
    window.onload = init();
```

The problem is that the global variable "visited" is not being reassigned.

I studied the variable scopes and operations, but due to some yet unknown reason it is not working as I expect.

I need the visited variable, because on page there is button, which after click on it, shows the content of file. So, if it is pressed, it reloads the webpage with the content from file. Thus, if the page had already been reloaded with the content from file and the user reloads the page, the data in form shall be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `cookies`, `local` or `session` storage for this case.

Answer (score 0):

[As described on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp):
In order to reset a form, you can add the following line:

```
document.getElementById('formId').reset();
```

or

```
document.forms['formName'].reset();
```